# auto layout conflict with height constraint in custom keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints, custom-keyboard

I am developing a custom multilingual keyboard for iphone and ipad and i am stuck with a UI thing that i am unable to retain the proper UI in case of orientation change of the device.

My final target is to achieve more keyboard height (default ios keyboard height with suggestions) in both landscape + portrait mode +  in both iPhone + iPad devices.

But as soon as i get the auto resizing up and running (not auto layout), i am not able to add constraints to keyboard height (auto layout disabled in Xib file).

If i add constraints by enabling auto layout, i loose the autoresizing of the subviews so  that they adjust them selves according to the device screen.

My basic issue is that i do not know which way to go, So that i can focus only there.

following is the code i am using to add constraints programatically.

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];
    CGFloat _expandedHeight = 273;
    NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                 relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem: nil
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                multiplier: 0.0
                                  constant: _expandedHeight];
    [self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];


}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.inputView = (UIInputView *)Keyboard;
        [self updateViewConstraints];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");
}

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    NSLog(@"viewWillLayoutSubviews");
    [self updateViewConstraints];
}
```

Any suggestion would be great!
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `updateViewConstraints ` will add new constraint everytime its called. You need to consider remove also. This is just a suggestion I dont have ful domain of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid constraint conflicts in a keyboard extension would be:

1. Create a keyboard background view which will contain all subviews
   of a keyboard.
2. Autolayout only the keyboard background view
   with the root keyboard controller view to make the background view to have the same frame as the root view. Do not autolayout all other
   subviews.
3. Manually layout all the keyboard subviews in
   viewDidLayoutSubviews of the root keyboard controller after invoking
   `[super viewDidLayoutSubviews]`.

In addition, by doing this, keyboard extension launching speed will be dramatically increased because of far less amount of auto-layout calculations.

Comment: thanks, i ll apply what you are saying and get back to you. also could you please confirm that i should create all the views in a particular uiview and then autolayout it and not auto layout anything else.

Comment: it is not possible to make auto layout only the background views as it will be applied to all other views as well. It might be possible that i am not able to apply the same so could you please explain a bit more in detail.. thanks